# Can I convert a wall lamp into a usb socket?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, lamp

I've recently moved house, and there is a wall lamp, see picture, which we never use, and i was wondering if i could put a usb socket there instead so i could charge bike lights and similar accessories.

Is this possible? Safe? Stupid? I have no clue, so any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: There are Edison A19 screw-in USB chargers (usually extending the socket for use with a bulb also)

Comment: What sort of box is behind the fixture?

Answer (score 3):

While there are other options involving wiring, the safest option that does not involve an electrician is a light bulb to outlet adapter.  Here, the version for use in countries with Edison base A19 bulbs:

[image: Screw in outlet adapter for lamp fixture Edison base A19]

Someone else can add advice for other regions.  In the case of a USB socket a third prong is generally not required, though chargers in the UK generally have a plastic fake third prong anyway.

Comment: These things cost less than $2.  There are also versions that allow you to keep the bulb socket, but add an electrical plug socket.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of screw up in lamp adapters for usb charging... this one keeps the bulb socket and offers a switch for turning it on and off as well...

[https://www.amazon.com/Power-LampCharger-Adapter-Charging-Station/dp/B07P9SDHRY/ref=asc_df_B07P9SDHRY/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312727440900&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16039082328258743868&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9052336&hvtargid=pla-662025529566&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P9SDHRY)